# Remove Eclipse's extra margins in Linux (Ubuntu XFCE)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, eclipse, xfce, gtk

I can't get rid of an ugly and wasting-space margin below the menubar in Eclipse:

[image: margin appears below menubar]

I have followed a number of tutorials for improving the rendering of Eclipse on Ubuntu, including using a custom compact theme like the one in: [How can I make Eclipse draw tabs more like native ones?](https://superuser.com/questions/399514/how-can-i-make-eclipse-to-draw-the-tabs-more-likely-the-native-ones)

This really becomes a problem on debug perspective where I have the window divided in three views vertically.

Also, any tips for reducing other extra margins like in the tabs or status bars are welcome.